# Di Perna-Lions theory for transport equation

Tags: analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Does someone know if some notes on the topic mentioned in the title are available online?
I'm reading the paper "Ordinary differential equations, transport theory and Sobolev spaces" by Di Perna and Lions but I have some doubts.

Comment: If you dont get an answer here, try mathoverflow

Comment: There are [lecture notes by Ambrosio](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-75914-0_1), but they are (i) behind a paywall; (ii) more about subsequent work in this field than the paper itself.      If you have concrete questions about the content of the paper, you can ask them here as they arise.